# 'RLMResults' is not convertible to 'RLMObject'

Tags: swift, realm

データベースの行を削除しようとすると、`realm.deleteObject`の行で「`'RLMResults' is not convertible to 'RLMObject'`」というエラーが表示されてしまいます。色々調べてみてもあまり`Realm`の使い方が載ったサイトを見つけることができません。初歩的なことだと思いますが、どうすればデータを削除することができるでしょうか？
また、テーブルを丸ごと削除するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？
どなたか分かる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。すみませんが、よろしくお願いします。

```
import Foundation

class Word: RLMObject {
    var id = 0
    var speech = ""
    var word = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

データの削除処理

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
realm.transactionWithBlock({ () -> Void in
    realm.deleteObject(Word.objectsWhere("id == 1"))
})
```

---追記---

「`deleteObject`」を「`deleteObjects`」に変えて試したところエラーがなくなりコンパイルができるようになりました。しかし、いざプログラムを実行してみるとプログラムが動かなくなってしまいました。その後色々試してみて`Word.objectsWhere("speech == A")`とするとプログラムが正常に動き、データも削除することができました。これはどういうことなのでしょうか？なぜidを指定して削除できないのでしょうか？

---追記---

```
import Foundation

class Word: RLMObject {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var speech = ""
    dynamic var word = ""

    override class func primaryKey() -> String {
        return "id"
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
    realm.transactionWithBlock({ () -> Void in
        realm.deleteObjects(Word.allObjects())
    })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### データの削除について

> どうすればデータを削除することができるでしょうか？

下記のコードも、`Word.objectsWhere("speech == A")`としたコードも私が試した限りではどちらも正しく動いていますが、「プログラムが動かなくなってしまいました。」というのは具体的にはどのようなことが起こっているのでしょうか？
コード全体を提示したり、もう少し詳しい状況を教えていただくことはできますか？

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
realm.transactionWithBlock({ () -> Void in
    realm.deleteObject(Word.objectsWhere("id == 1"))
})
```

また、「idを指定して削除」は、プライマリキーを指定して削除したいということだと思いますので、まず、プライマリキーを指定してオブジェクトを取得するのは次のように書けます。

```
Word(forPrimaryKey: 1)
```

これはプライマリキーを指定しているので、RLMResultsではなく、Wordオブジェクト（もしくはnil）が返ってくるので、`deleteObject`メソッドに渡すことができます。

この方がプライマリキーを指定して１件削除をする、という処理としてはわかりやすい書き方かと思います。

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
realm.transactionWithBlock({ () -> Void in
    realm.deleteObject(Word(forPrimaryKey: 1))
})
```

#### 任意のテーブルのデータをすべて削除するには

> テーブルを丸ごと削除するにはどうすればいいでしょうか？

テーブルを丸ごと削除するには次のように書きます。
対象のモデルのデータをすべて取得して、`deleteObjects`メソッドに渡します。

```
let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
realm.transactionWithBlock { () -> Void in
    realm.deleteObjects(Word.allObjects())
}
```

実際にテーブルのデータ全件がロードされるわけではありませんので、この処理はとても高速に動作します。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。表示されるViewControllerのviewDidLoadでご回答にあるrealm.deleteObjects(Word.allObjects())を書いたら最初のLaunchScreenの画面のまま動かなくなってしまいます。
プログラムをもう少し詳しく載せたいと思います。
今少し時間がないので大変申し訳ないのですが、少々お待ちください。
すみません。

Comment: 削除がうまく動かなかったというのも含めて、変な動きをしているのはモデルのプロパティにdynamicが付いていないことが原因じゃないかと思います。一度、モデルの定義を修正して、再度試してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: dynamicを付けた後のモデルクラスとdeleteObjectsの記述のある部分を追記いたしました。dynamicを付けて普通に実行するとデータベースの中身を出力することができました！しかしrealm.deleteObjects(Word.allObjects())でテーブルを削除しようとするとアプリが動かなくなってしまいます。Realm Browserで直接データを削除しようとすると、Realm Browserが落ちてしまったりと、どうすることもできずまた詰まってしまいました。。。realm.deleteObject(Word(forPrimaryKey: 1))のようにプライマリーキーで指定してもアプリが動かなくなってしまいます。
dynamicが付いて「なかった」ことが原因なのかなと思い、テーブルを作り直したいのですが、どうすればアプリが動かなくなることなくテーブルを作り直すことができるでしょうか？

Comment: データを消してしまった構わないなら、デバイスまたはシミュレータからアプリを削除して再インストール、という手順でやり直すのが一番簡単です。

Comment: アプリをアンインストールして試したところ、正常な動作で動かすことができました！最後までお付合いくださり誠に感謝しています！本当にありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

`deleteObject`ではなくて`deleteObjects`が正しいのではないでしょうか。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。「deleteObjects」で試したところエラーがなくなりプログラムを動かすことができるようになりました！しかし、deleteObjectsをしたところ、エラーも出ずにプログラムが動かなくなってしまいました。削除の仕方が間違っているのでしょうか？ちなみに上記の削除処理のコードはviewDidAppear内で行いました。